# Installing Postgresql 8.1.17 server on RHEL

Tags: linux, installation, postgresql-8.1

I have a my production database on PostgreSQL 8.1.17 server.
I want to migrate it from one Linux server to another.

On another Linux server I am not able to install the PostgreSQL 8.1.17 server using rpm.
I got the rpm file from http://yum.postgresql.org/8.1/redhat/rhel-5-x86_64/ link.
But while updating rpm repository using rpm -i postgresql-8.1.17-1PGDG.rhel4.x86_64.rpm
I am getting below error.

error: Failed dependencies:
        libcrypto.so.4()(64bit) is needed by postgresql-8.1.17-1PGDG.rhel4.x86_64
        libpq.so.4()(64bit) is needed by postgresql-8.1.17-1PGDG.rhel4.x86_64
        libreadline.so.4()(64bit) is needed by postgresql-8.1.17-1PGDG.rhel4.x86_64
        libssl.so.4()(64bit) is needed by postgresql-8.1.17-1PGDG.rhel4.x86_64
        libtermcap.so.2()(64bit) is needed by postgresql-8.1.17-1PGDG.rhel4.x86_64

How will I resolve this dependency.

The End Of Life (EOL) dates for 8.1 version is November 2010. Does it mean we won't be able to install 8.1 version after November 2010. Referring below link.

http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

I don't want to upgrade the PostgreSQL version for now.

Answer (score 0):

Make a full systen backup, then launch the following command:

```
rpm -i --nodeps postgresql-8.1.17-1PGDG.rhel4.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Hi Gino, here what do you mean by system backup.

Comment: I would create a full disk image with partimage or acronis true image